# Cannot query SQL Server table containing Arabic from my Java app using HQL

Tags: java, sql-server, hibernate, unicode, hql

I'm working on a Java Swing application where I query a table in a SQL Server database. This table contains some data that is in Arabic, Chinese etc... But the problem is that I am not getting any results while using this query: (var can be Arabic or any other language):

```
from Table T where T.columnName like '%"+var+"%'
```

I did some searching and then tried the following:

```
from Table T where T.columnName like N'%"+var+"%'
```

I am getting this error message on NetBeans:

> Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0"
>
> org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException: unexpected token: N near line 1

Can someone help me with this problem? I'm confused knowing that this same last query worked perfectly in SQL Server Management Studio.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that HQL != T-SQL, and you are mixing the two. HQL is pseudo-SQL and so does not understand the T-SQL-specific dialect handling of Unicode strings (i.e. the `N`-prefix on string literals).

So, it seems like you have two options:

1. **HQL**

   Continue using `createQuery` as follows:

   ```java
   session.createQuery("from Table T " +
                       "where T.column like :fltr ")
          .setParameter( "fltr", "%" + content + "%", StringNVarcharType.INSTANCE )
          .list();
   ```
2. **T-SQL**

   Switch to using `createSQLQuery` as follows:

   ```java
   session.createSQLQuery("select * from Table T where T.column like N'%" +
                          content + "%' ").list();
   ```

   There *might* be more to do here, but I have no way to test it.

More info and examples can be found at: [Hibernate ORM 5.2.4.Final User Guide](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/current/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html):

- HQL code above based on Example 334
- `StringNVarcharType` type found in chart of [2.3.1. Hibernate-provided BasicTypes: Table 1. Standard BasicTypes](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/current/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#basic-provided)
- T-SQL code above based on Example 402 and Example 423

Comment: Hi!I tested your first solution and it worked like a charm!just what I was seaching for! Thank you...just a small question though, if I have multiple parameters, how can I proceed with the setParameters?

Comment: @TheLila I guess you can just chain the `setParameter` calls, like `session.createQuery(...).setParameter(...).setParameter(...)....list();`

Comment: @TheLila Yes, as TT. mentioned, you should be able to chain any number of parameters (and other functions/methods). Please see the linked Hibernate documentation for a more complete description of your options.

Answer (score 0):

Declare your var as NVARCHAR, and remove the quotations.

```
FROM Table T WHERE T.columnName LIKE N'%' + var + N'%'
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the following HQL:

```
String hql = "FROM Table T WHERE T.columnName LIKE CONCAT('%', :columnValue, '%')";
session.createQuery(hql)
       .setString("columnValue", "Sample Value")
       .list();
```

Comment: Hi Jobin.  Did you test this explicitely for Arabic text in an `NVARCHAR` column? I am asking this because the OP might have abandoned the question and I am not familiar with HQL so I cannot really test this myself. I was planning on granting the bounty to the answer the OP thought answered his question, that's why I'm asking.

Comment: @TT. and Jobin: I wouldn't expect this to work. It should effectively produce the query that the O.P. originally had: the correct parameter value enclosed in a VARCHAR literal (i.e. no `N`-prefix). The trick is to tell Hibernate that the parameter datatype is `NVARCHAR`.